# Render camera to .obj or generated opengl surface

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, avfoundation

I'm trying to create some funny mirror effects in iPhone app, i have Apple sample GLVideoFrame, from  [WWDC2010](http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/getSoftware?code=y&source=x&bundleID=20645) where they are rendering AVCapture output to glView, but when I replace Texcoords and Verticles with my own exported from Blender or generated from blender .OBJ using obj2opengl , I haven't see anything, but if I try the same obj with OBJLoaderSampler, it shows very well.

What I'm doing wrong ?